# Surd Partition Problem

Tags: computational-complexity, np

Could the following "Surd Partition" problem be NP complete? Note that if the square roots are omitted in the following then the problem is well known to have a polynomial solution.

**Surd Partition**

Instance: A collection of positive integers $b_{i}, i=1,..,n$ such that $1 \leq b_{1}\leq b_{2}\leq..\leq b_{n}\leq n$

Question: Is there a subset S of {1,2,..,n} in which

\begin{eqnarray}
\left| \sum_{i\in S}  \sqrt{b_{i}} - \sum_{i\in S^c}  \sqrt{b_{i}} \right| < 1?
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: What is the polynomial solution for the result of removing square roots from that problem? $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution .

Comment: As far as I can see, the problem as stated is not even known to be in NP: if you fix $S$, determining whether the sum has absolute value exactly $1$ is a variant of the sum of square roots problem, which is only known to be in the counting hierarchy. I don't see how having the $b_i$ in unary would necessarily help, as the sum has still length $n$.

Comment: Specifically, per http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/TOPP/P33.html , the best known bounds only show that in order to check $\bigl|\sum_S\sqrt{b_i}-\sum_{S^c}\sqrt{b_i}\bigr|<1$ by computing approximations of the square roots, one can get away with $2^{O(n/\log n)}$ bits of accuracy, which is nowhere near polynomial.

Comment: Thanks so much for the responses. The polynolial solution if the sq roots are removed is given in Garey and Johnsons standard text Computers and Intractability pp90-91. Thanks Emil for your guidance - better to suggest that this problem might be NP-hard.